# How to write unit tests for pipes using Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

How to write a unit test case for pipes?

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { IDropDownItem } from '@app/interfaces';
import { IDepartment } from '../interfaces';


class DepartmentDDItem implements IDropDownItem {
  public value: number;
  public id: number;
  public name: string;

  constructor(res: IDepartment) {
    this.value = res.id;
    this.id = res.id;
    this.name = res.name;
  }
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'formatDepartmetsData'
})
export class FormatDepartmetsDataPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: IDepartment[]): IDropDownItem[] {
    return !data || !Array.isArray(data) ?
      data : data.map(item => new DepartmentDDItem(item))
  }
}
```

Interface of IDepartment

```
export interface IDepartment {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Interface of IDropDownItem

```
 export interface IDropDownItem {
  value: any;
  name: string;
  checked?: boolean;
  extra?: string;
  [key:string]: any;
}
```

So how can I pass it to  expect(pipe.transform('abc')).toBe('ABC');

Comment: Call the transform method, see if it does the right thing? Maybe read https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: Unit test is a way to test the code behavior, it does mean you will give an input to a method and test the expected output

Comment: hi, @jonrsharpe  I have added my all code so can you tell me how to pass data inside transform method

Answer (score 2):

Construct the pipe. Test pipe's `transform()`.

```js
describe('TitleCasePipe', () => {
  // This pipe is a pure, stateless function so no need for BeforeEach
  const pipe = new TitleCasePipe();

  it('transforms "abc" to "Abc"', () => {
    expect(pipe.transform('abc')).toBe('Abc');
  });

  it('transforms "abc def" to "Abc Def"', () => {
    expect(pipe.transform('abc def')).toBe('Abc Def');
  });

  // ... more tests ...
});
```

https://angular.io/guide/testing-pipes

Comment: I have Added IDropDownItem & IDepartment so now what to change @Joosep.P